# Finding reachable vertices for every vertex in a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, theory, graph-theory

I know that brute force approach to do this is perform DFS on all the vertices of the graph.So for this algorithm the complexity would be O(V|V+E|). But is there more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the impression from papers like http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/144985/todsfinal.pdf that there is no algorithm that does better than `O(VE)` or `O(V^3)` in the general case. For sparse graphs and other special graphs there are faster algorithms. It seems, however, that you can still make improvements by separating "index construction" from "query", if you have some idea of the number of queries that will be made on the data. If there are going to be a lot of queries, `O(1)` is possible for queries if all the data is pre-computed (DFS or Floyd-Warshall, etc.) and stored in `O(n^2)` space. On the other hand, if there are going to be relatively few queries, space and/or index construction time can be reduced at the expense of query time.

Answer (score 3):

I really suspect that there isn't a known better algorithm for general graphs. All the papers I found on the subject [1] [2] describe algorithms that run in O(|V| * |E|) time. That isn't better than your naïve attempt in the worst case.

Even the wikipedia page [3] says the fastest algorithms reduce the problem to matrix multiplication, which the fastest algorithms are only marginally better than your baseline.

[1] http://ion.uwinnipeg.ca/~ychen2/conferencePapers/tranRelationCopy.pdf

[2] http://www.vldb.org/conf/1988/P382.PDF

[3] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure#Algorithms

Comment: Could you please explain how to apply fast multiplication to this problem

Comment: @teja Don't know if there are faster algorithms, but you can use the adjacency matrix M, and perform M^|V|. Using the fastest matrix multiplication algorithms (and exponentiation by squaring) this is O(|V|^2.37 log |V|)

Answer (score 1):

**[EDIT: As pointed out by kraskevich, the final query step can be worse than I had originally claimed: up to O(|V|^2) even for an output of size O(|V|), which is no better than ordinary DFS without any preprocessing.]**.

In the worst case, O(|V|^2) space would be needed to store all this information explicitly -- i.e., to store the complete list of reachable vertices for each vertex (think of a graph in which every vertex has an edge to every other vertex).  But it's possible to represent it in such a way that only O(|V|) space is needed, and this representation can be built in O(|V|+|E|) time, <strike>and a query on it will only take time proportional to the size of the answer (number of reachable vertices)</strike>.

The basic idea is: **Every vertex in a [strongly connected component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) (SCC) can reach every other vertex in the same SCC (this is the definition of SCC), and can reach all vertices in SCCs that it can reach, and no other vertices.**

1. Find all SCCs; this can be done in O(|V|+|E|) time.  Build a table SCC, so that SCC(u) = i if the SCC of u is i (both vertices in G and SCCs can be represented as integers).  Afterwards make another pass through this table to build a dual table, Verts, so that Verts(i) contains a list of all vertices in the ith SCC.
2. Build a new graph G' whose vertices are the SCCs of G.  G' will necessarily be acyclic.

So, given a vertex u in G, look up its SCC, SCC(u).  Call this i.  Perform a DFS through G' starting at vertex i: For each vertex (of G') j encountered during this DFS, output every vertex (of G) in Verts(j).

Comment: Actually, it looks like the time in the worst case is not proportional to the size of the answer. Imagine a graph which has three layers. There are all possible edges from the third to the second layer and from the second to the first layer. It is a DAG, so finding SCC does not change it. However, running a DFS from any vertex of the third layer involves examining all edges(`O(n^2)`), but there are at most `O(n)` reachable vertices. So running a DFS from all vertices of the third layer results in `O(n^3)` time, which is not better than a naive solution.

Comment: @kraskevich: You're absolutely right.  I can't see a way around this...  Can you?  Is there perhaps some way to efficiently query for the next child of a vertex that avoids already-seen vertices?

Comment: @kraskevich: I realise now that such an efficient query would imply that DFS can be done in time less than O(|V|+|E|)!